# Error inserting a record using Laravel Cashier and many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5, laravel-cashier

I have a many-to-many relationship between the User and Subscription tables in Laravel, as follows:

In Subscription.php:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In User.php

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I create a new subscription in Cashier (using Stripe) as follows:

```
$user->newSubscription($planname, $planname)->create();
```

(Note that the product and plan names are currently the same and the user's card is on record, hence the lack of a stripe token.)

But when I run this I get an error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `subscriptions` (`name`, `stripe_id`, `stripe_plan`, `quantity`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (projects, sub_EY1zRywZ1jUjLl, projects, 1, 2019-02-17 20:07:36, 2019-02-17 20:07:36))

I'm not sure if the relationship is causing the issue or whether it's my new subscription code. How do I fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

I've made the following change and I still get the same error:

```
$user->newSubscription($planname, $planname)->create(null,[
    'user_id' => $user->id, 
]);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've made the following change and the exact same error still occurs:

```
 $id = Auth::id();
 $user = User::find($id);

  // $user = Auth::user();
```

Comment: I removed the many-to-many relationship and Cashier immediately worked. It's not really a solution but I can work without the many-to-many relationship so i'll leave it like this for now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `Billable` trait added to your `User` model?

Comment: Yes:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Billable;
    use UserHasTeams;

Comment: Could you share the code where you are declaring the `$user` variable?

Comment: $user = Auth::user();

Answer (score 0):

```
General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value.
```

According to this, I think you need to fill the **user_id** column with an id value via **$id = Auth::id();**

---

Taken from laravel documentation:

**Additional User Details**

If you would like to specify additional customer details, you may do so by passing them as the second argument to the create method:

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($stripeToken, [
    'email' => $email, 
]);
```

**UPDATE**

Could you try this one:

```
 $id = Auth::id();
 $user = User::find($id);

 $user->newSubscription($planname, $planname)->create();
```

Comment: I've made some changes following your comment but I still get the same error, see updated question.

Comment: No, that didn't work.either. Exactly the same error message.

Comment: Hmm, $fillable array should contain "user_id" value. Did you check it?

Comment: of Subscription model? Yes:     protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id', 'stripe_plan', 'stripe_id', 'quantity'];

Comment: `'strict' => false`, into **config/database.php** within mysql array. I hope it helps. I found this solution on laravel.io(the answer is taken from somebody's question who has a similar problem like yours: 'doesn't have a default value while inserting').

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. It allows the entry to be created in the database,, but it inserts 0, not the user id